# MS Access: How can i select columns from different tables

Tags: ms-access, multiple-tables, multiple-select-query

In MS Access, I need to select a single row with many data from different tables with this query:

```
select top 1 a.colname,b.colname,c.colname 
from tba a, tbb b, tbc c 
where a.colname = 'efg' or
      b.colname ='efg' or
      c.colname ='efg'
```

I will get data perfectly when **'efg'** is matched with at least 1 from the 3 tables BUT if it does not match with any of them I will get MS Access frozen with wait cursor. I guessed it is looping for some reason. I only able to stop it with **END TASK** in Windows's task manager.

How is my query and can any expert explain or suggest different techniques to avoid this?

Thank you.

Comment: How large are each of the three tables?

Comment: avg record is around 5,000, not so big.

Comment: You are using not joined tables, it means that if you have 5000 records in each table, select may return 5000*5000*5000=125,000,000,000 rows, of course Access will hang and even operating system may crash. Join tables first.

Comment: Get it. Thanks sir.

Comment: Another question:
because of my expected result is as a single return row, how do you suggest to do after getting the joined table?

Answer (score 0):

If the field in each of the 3 tables is the same field then you could use unions then select the first record returned.

```
select top 1 d.*
FROM (      SELECT a.colname  as colName
            FROM tba a
            WHERE a.colname = 'efg'
        UNION ALL
            SELECT b.colnamee as colName      
            FROM tbb b 
            WHERE B.colName='efg' 
        UNION ALL
            SELECT c.colname as colName      
            FROM tbc c
            WHERE c.colName='efg'
     ) as d
```

Or if they are 3 different fields then like others have suggested you could join the three tables to reduce the servers load.

Comment: thank you so much ClintB. It seems that this is my bad idea of getting result data.